# Desktop manager for XP(dual monitor)

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, graphics-card

I have nvidia card. I am using two DVI ports for dual monitor. Now my requirement is I want to set some window to be open on specific monitor only. For that i have tried nview option. And it is get reset when we reboot machine with single monitor and when we connect second one all the output comes only in primary(single monitor which was connected earlier second one). I want to get the profile back after reboot with single and then dual monitor. Is there any other tool to do this?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  This sounds like a bug or conflict with nview and Windows XP.  If you have control over the source for the program itself you can set the behavior within the program itself.

Comment: I have two monitors. And i have set to display start menu in secondary. After i disconnect one monitor and reboot everything comes in single monitor. Then whenever i connect the other monitor the start menu should be appear as initial setup. Hope now you can get my question.

Comment: Why are disconnecting the monitor.  Sounds like you want to use something other then nview that allows more control or automatic scripting support.

Comment: I want the setup back after disconnecting too. is it possible?

Comment: Multi-Monitor supprt in Windows XP was basic at best.  If you are booting into Windows without the second monitor your desktop settings are being cleared by doing that.  The program in question likel looks to that configuration to function.  If you disconnect the monitor make sure Windows XP isn't running, and both monitors are connected, before booting the computer.